# Replace a letter with another from the last word from the last two lines of a text file

Tags: awk, sed

How could I possibly replace a character with another, selecting the last word from the last two lines of a text file in shell, using only a single command? In my case, replacing every occurrence of `a` with `E` from the last word only.

Like, from a text file containing this:

```
tree;apple;another
mango.banana.half
monkey.shelf.karma
```

to this:

```
tree;apple;another
mango.banana.hElf
monkey.shelf.kErmE
```

I tried using `sed -n 'tail -2 'mytext.txt' -r 's/[a]+/E/*$//'` but it doesn't work (my error: `sed expression #1, char 10: unknown option to 's`).

Comment: What's the _last word_ if the delimiter changes midway, ie. please define _word_? Also, would you like to replace every instance of the letter in that _word_ or maybe first or last?

Comment: ... ie. will `karma` transform to `kErmE`, `kErma` or `karmE`.

Comment: Is it always true that only the last 2 lines use `.` between "words" while earlier lines use `;` like in your example?

Comment: @EdMorton yes sir

Comment: @Marcus-SilviuIlisie in that case, `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} NF>1{gsub(/a/, "E", $NF)} 1'` will work

Answer (score 9):

Could you please try following, `tac` + `awk` solution. Completely based on OP's samples only.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk 'FNR<=2{if(/;/){FS=OFS=";"};if(/\./){FS=OFS="."};gsub(/a/,"E",$NF)} 1' | 
tac
```

Output with shown samples is:

```
tree;apple;another
mango.banana.hElf
monkey.shelf.kErmE
```

***NOTE:*** Change `gsub` to `sub` in case you want to substitute only very first occurrence of character `a` in last field.

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```sh
sed -E 'N;${:a;s/a([^a.]*)$/E\1/mg;ta};P;D' file
```

Open a two line window throughout the length of the file by using the `N` to append the next line to the previous and the `P` and `D` commands to print then delete the first of these. Thus at the end of the file, signified by the `$` address the last two lines will be present in the pattern space.

Using the `m` multiline flag on the substitution command, as well as the `g` global flag and a loop between `:a` and `ta`, replace any `a` in the last word (delimited by `.`) by an `E`.

Thus the first pass of the substitution command will replace the `a` in `half` and the last `a` in `karma`. The next pass will match nothing in the penultimate line and replace the `a` in `karmE`. The third pass will match nothing and thus the `ta` command will fail and the last two lines will printed with the required changes.

Comment: Nice and short. Can you clarify one point for me? Given how you use this `N`-`P`-`D` idiom, I understand that `$` will match right after `N` has been executed on the **second to last** line. Is this the case, or I am misunderstanding it?

Comment: @Enrico say you have a 3 line file. seds cycle reads in the first line (minus the newline) into the pattern space. The `N` command appends  a newline and the second line minus a newline to the pattern space. The address is now 2 and not the end of file so the `P` prints the first line and the `D` deletes the first line and the following newline. The cycle does not append a line as the pattern space is not empty (`D` command action). The `N` command appends a newline and the third line. The address is now 3 and also `$` because it is the last line, substitution occurs. `P` and `D` and then`N`

Comment: @Enrico note the last `N` command cannot append anything and sed cycle terminates after having printed whatever was in the pattern space (plus a newline,if the file was terminated in a newline). Thus commands following the `N` command are never invoked when the `N` command tries to read passed the end of file.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Sed, here's a solution:

```bash
tac input_file | sed -E '1,2{h;s/.*[^a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]+)/\1/;s/a/E/;x;s/(.*[^a-zA-Z]).*/\1/;G;s/\n//}' | tac
```

One tiny detail: in your question you say you want to replace *a letter*, but then you transform `karma` in `kErme`, so what is this? If you meant to write `kErma`, then the command above will work; if you meant to write `kErmE`, then you have to change it just a bit: the `s/a/E/` should become `s/a/E/g`.

Answer (score 3):

With `tac+perl`

```
$ tac ip.txt | perl -pe 's/\w+\W*$/$&=~tr|a|E|r/e if $.<=2' | tac
tree;apple;another
mango.banana.hElf
monkey.shelf.kErmE
```

- `\w+\W*$` match last word in the line, `\W*` allows any possible trailing non-word characters to be matched as well. Change `\w` and `\W` accordingly if numbers and underscores shouldn't be considered as word characters - for ex: `[a-zA-Z]+[^a-zA-Z]*$`
- `$&=~tr|a|E|r` change all `a` to `E` only for the matched portion
- `e` flag to enable use of Perl code in replacement section instead of string

To do it in one command, you can slurp the entire input as single string (assuming this'll fit available memory):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\w+\W*$(?=(\n.*)?\n\z)/$&=~tr|a|E|r/gme'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for`split()` 4th arg since in [the comments of another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366700/replace-a-letter-with-another-from-the-last-word-from-the-last-two-lines-of-a-te/64368237#comment113823273_64366736) the field delimiter is *every sequence of alphanumeric and numeric characters*:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    pc=2                        # previous counter, ie how many are affected
}
{
    for(i=pc;i>=1;i--)          # buffer to p hash, a FIFO
        if(i==pc && (i in p))   # when full, output 
            print p[i]
        else if(i in p)         # and keep filling
            p[i+1]=p[i]         # above could be done using mod also
    p[1]=$0
}
END {
    for(i=pc;i>=1;i--) {
        n=split(p[i],t,/[^a-zA-Z0-9\r]+/,seps)   # split on non alnum
        gsub(/a/,"E",t[n])                       # replace
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++) {
            p[i]=(j==1?"":p[i] seps[j-1]) t[j]   # pack it up
        }
        print p[i]                               # output
    }
}' file
```

Output:

```
tree;apple;another
mango.banana.hElf
monkey.shelf.kErmE
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ awk -v n=2 '
    NR>n { print p[NR%n] }
    { p[NR%n] = $0 }
    END {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            match(p[i],/(.*[^[:alnum:]])(.*)/,a)
            print a[1] gensub(/a/,"E","g",a[2])
        }
    }
' file
tree;apple;another
mango.banana.hElf
monkey.shelf.kErmE
```

or with any awk:

```
awk -v n=2 '
    NR>n { print p[NR%n] }
    { p[NR%n] = $0 }
    END {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            match(p[i],/.*[^[:alnum:]]/)
            lastWord = substr(p[i],1+RLENGTH)
            gsub(/a/,"E",lastWord )
            print substr(p[i],1,RLENGTH) lastWord 
        }
    }
' file
```

If you want to do it for the last 50 lines of a file instead of the last 2 lines just change `-v n=2` to `-v n=50`.

The above assumes there are at least `n` lines in your input.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help you ? on GNU `awk`

```
$ cat file
tree;apple;another
mango.banana.half
monkey.shelf.karma

$ tac file | awk 'NR<=2{s=gensub(/(.*)([.;])(.*)$/,"\\3",1);gsub(/a/,"E",s); print gensub(/(.*)([.;])(.*)$/,"\\1\\2",1) s;next}1' | tac
tree;apple;another
mango.banana.hElf
monkey.shelf.kErmE
```

Better Readable version :

```
$ tac file | awk 'NR<=2{
   s=gensub(/(.*)([.;])(.*)$/,"\\3",1);
   gsub(/a/,"E",s); 
   print gensub(/(.*)([.;])(.*)$/,"\\1\\2",1) s;
   next
}1' | tac
```

Comment: I receive this error: "awk: line 2: function gensub never defined
awk: line 2: function gensub never defined"

Comment: @Marcus-SilviuIlisie GNU awk, I am on `$ awk --version
GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.6-p2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
`

Comment: Hedge what command did you use to see your version?

Comment: `awk --version `

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk` you can set `FS` with the two separators, then `gsub` for the replacement in `$3`, the third field, if `NR>1`

```
awk -v FS=";|[.]"  'NR>1 {gsub("a", "E",$3)}1' OFS="." file

tree;apple;another
mango.banana.hElf
monkey.shelf.kErmE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let `sed` repeat changing an a into E only for the last word with a label.

```
tac mytext.txt| sed -r ':a; 1,2s/a(\w*)$/E\1/; ta' | tac
```